# scrabble combination generator generating combinations that cannot be made

Tags: python, string, combinations

so I made a program for scrabble where given an input of characters, it prints all possible words, however it is printing words that cannot be made, like nun when the input is run. could someone please help me? I cant figure out how to fix this. here is the code.

````
from itertools import product
from english_words import english_words_set

a = input()
x = True
li = list(a)
for comb in product(li, repeat=len(li)):
    b = ''.join(comb)
    if b in english_words_set:
        i = 0
        while i < len(li):
            if not li[i] in b:
                x = False
                i += 1
            if li[i] in b:
                x = True
                i += 1
        if x == True:
            print(b)```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you try permutations from itertools?

```
from itertools import permutations

a = input()

for r in range(1, len(a)+1):
    for item in permutations(a,r):
        s = "".join(item)
        print(s)
```

**Input**

```
run
```

**Output**

```
r
u
n
ru
rn
ur
un
nr
nu
run
rnu
urn
unr
nru
nur
```